# How can I find the top and bottom most point from the intersection of three circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have three circles with equal radius ($r$). I want to formulate the bottom and topmost point of their intersection as a function of $r$.

[image: Sample figure]

Comment: The distance will also depend heavily on the circles centers.

Comment: Yes. I also have the centers of the circles. I am trying to formulate the points (top and bottom) as a function of radius and centers.

Comment: Would you like to share those centers with us?

Comment: consider the centers are (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3). Actually, I want a generalized formula that works for all cases.

Comment: What you mean by top or bottom? seems like the y values could suffice to determine.

Comment: Solve for intersection as function of r. It is possible that they will not intersect.